# Ethan does not run

Tags: unity, animation, animator

I just imported Ethan - the third person character to my Unity 2019 project and I moved him around a plane. But for some reason he doesn't run, only walk. I logged the `m_ForwardAmount` variable which is the value the Forward parameter receives in the animator. Its value is 0.999965. But when I look in the animator parameter tab the value I see is around 0.4555. Another thing to note is that when I hard-code changing the value of `m_ForwardAmount` to 1, Ethan runs.

Does anyone have any idea why this happens? Thank you!